# Can't bind to ngClass.<breakpoint> or ngStyle.<breakpoint>

Tags: angular, flexbox

I get `Can't bind to 'ngClass.sm' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.` on this [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/m8ZcRR2ZXgWdUwmdRXuc/). Could this be a bug or am I using the [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) api wrong?

Comment: which version of flex-layout?  this was a known issue in earlier versions (you had to bind to ngClass first and then you were able to bind to ngClass.sm for eg)

Comment: The plunker uses `https://unpkg.com/@angular/flex-layout/bundles/flex-layout.umd.js` which redirects to `https://unpkg.com/@angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-rc.1/bundles/flex-layout.umd.js`. On my local enviroment I'm an also using `2.0.0-rc.1`. Also I am binding to `ngClass` before `ngClass.sm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out its related to this bug https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/215
Use `class` and `style` until next release.